# WIndows docker container is not able to access sql server of host but can access one running on different host

Tags: sql-server, windows, docker

I am running a asp.net core application inside Windows 1709 docker container. The application needs to access sql server running on host system. Strangely it is not able to access the sql server instance running on host, however while I start up another sql server on different system on same network, the docker image can access that remote system. It is very strange. I made all necessary changes in the hosts file in docker, turned firewall off etc. This same sql server (which is not being accessed) can be accessed via docker running on another host, that means there is no problem with the service. What can be the problem here?
Thanks,
Debojit

Comment: Add connection strings for remote/local connection.

Comment: "ConnectionString": "Data Source=172.26.90.128;database=XXXXX;User Id=XXXX;Password=XXXXX". This same connection string works when accessed from containers in different host, problem occurs only when the docker is on the same host.